# How do hidden units in a Boltzmann Machine enforce this parity constraint?

Tags: neural-networks

In Ackley and Hinton's paper ["A Learning Algorithm for Boltzmann Machines"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.154.1370&rep=rep1&type=pdf), they write that

> A hidden unit would be needed, for
>   example, if the environment demanded
>   that the states of three visible units
>   should have even parity-a regularity
>   that cannot be enforced by pairwise
>   interactions alone.

Could someone explain how a hidden unit enforces this parity constraint? I'm having a hard time seeing what the structure and weights of the network would be. (In general, I see intuitively why hidden units add power, but I don't have a rigorous understanding.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are four allowed states of the visible units that have even parity:
[000] [110] [101] [011].

A simple (if costly) way to enforce this constraint would be to have 4 hidden units which correspond to these four allowed states.  The first unit has weights [---] to the visible units, the second-fourth have weights [++-], [+-+], and [-++], respectively.  If a hidden unit comes on, it enforces (via its weights) that the network adopt the corresponding state. (You could use strong inhibitory weights between the hidden units to ensure that only a single hidden unit is on at a time).

Comment: I would guess that there's a more elegant solution, but that's the first one I came up with.